# Spring Security - Is whitelable error page a security breach?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Is following page a result of a security breach?
[image]

I just want a confirmation from an expert. Adding a 401 custom page is nice to have but I don't think this is a security breach.

Comment: What you mean by security breach? This can happen for legitimate user if they are not authenticated.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam This is a security vulnerability as per some well known security audit firms :)

Comment: It's a vulnerability inasmuch as an attacker can better fingerprint your application. It's the same kind of vulnerability as having your URLs end in `.jsp` as that's a hint that the application is a servlet-based application. Shipping with the default Spring Boot error page can alert attackers to the fact that you are using Spring Boot. Besides, I think most want a better experience for their end users anyway! :)